# Let's get rid of [scripting] manually

Tags: discussion, tags

The [scripting](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) tag is a mess. It covers at least:

- Questions that are about the security of programs that happen to be written in an interpreted language, whether against:

  - local threats (bash, PowerShell, …) [[1]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1801/how-is-powershells-remotesigned-execution-policy-different-from-allsigned) [[2]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15585/can-a-sh-file-be-malware) [[3]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16068/what-can-i-do-to-separate-users-best-way-if-they-are-allowed-to-run-their-ruby)
  - server-side remote threats (PHP, …) [[1]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/is-this-enough-to-tackle-script-malicious-code-insertion-in-get-post-requests)
  - client remote threats (JavaScript, XSS, …) [[1]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4983/noscript-how-to-determine-which-sites-scripts-to-whitelist) [[2]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16247/does-google-chrome-protect-against-cross-site-scripting-xss)
- Questions about malware that happens to be written in a scripting language (often PHP or JavaScript) [[1]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/113577/what-is-this-injected-script-doing)
- Questions about automating a security-related task [[1]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14236/preferred-uac-configuration-in-enterprises-that-use-login-scripts-to-map-drives) [[2]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106816/newbie-attempt-at-nessus-script)

Only that last point may warrant a tag. On Unix & Linux, we have a [scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/scripting) that means that the question is specifically about automating a task as opposed to carrying it out interactively. On U&L, it's mildly useful; given that the determination is somewhat subjective, it's on the edge of being a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). Looking at the questions on this site, I don't think such a tag is warranted here.

Hence I propose to get rid of the [scripting](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) tag altogether. Given that it's often being used instead of a proper tag, we can't just burninate it, we need to do some manual retagging (48 questions).

Objections?

Comment: I agree. But as you say, since there are a non-trivial number of q's that need to be manually retagged - lets do it slowly... Please, everyone jump in (but only a bit at a time!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done and [scripting](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) is history.